# Changing baposter template font

Tags: fonts, baposter

I am using the baposter template and I want to change the font to Helvetica Neue. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `\setsansfont{HelveticaNeue}`

Comment: I placed this immediately after \documentclass... but it just results in the error "Undefined control sequence.".

Comment: The command is defined by `fontspec`. Do you use XeLaTeX or pdfLaTeX?

Comment: I use pdflatex. When I use fontspec it seems to mess up the entire poster template (everything becomes too large and exceeds the document size).

Comment: Voted unclear: no MWE and the suggestions in the comments work fine with a basic poster I just made up.

Comment: @Josh I believe you should set the font from the parent .tex file that uses baposter.cls e.g. 
`\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`.